# How to verify method, which has transactional lines, in unit test for Spring Boot Service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

i Have following UserServiceImpl Service Class:

```
@Service @Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    ...
    public void addRoleToUser(String username, String name) {
        User user = this.userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        Role role = this.roleRepository.findByName(name);
        user.getRoles().add(role);
    }
    
}
```

and it's corresponding test class:

```
public class UserServiceImplTest {

    @Mock private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Mock private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    private AutoCloseable autoCloseable;

    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;


    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(){
        autoCloseable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        userServiceImpl = new UserServiceImpl(userRepository, roleRepository);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws Exception{
        autoCloseable.close();
    }

    @Test
    void testAddRoleToUser() {
        ... // user and role def. here
        
        userServiceImpl.addRoleToUser(username, roleName);
        
        // what should be here?
    }
}
```

But how can I verify that `user.getRoles().add(role);` is invoked in unit test? Is using mockito, and ArgumentCaptor enough?

Thank you.

Comment: What if instead of void you return the updated ```User``` in the ```addRoleToUser``` method?

Comment: Nice suggestion. I try implement your suggestion and the answer that i marked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `userRepository` is a mock, you probably define a behaviour for the `findByUsername` call and return an object there. The object is created in the test method (in the "given" block), so you have access to it after calling the method (in the "then" block). You can simply verify if the object contains a given role like so (AssertJ ussage assumed):

```java
assertThat(user.getRoles())
   .contains(role);
```

`roleRepository` is also a mock, so the `role` object is probably also available in the test. If it was not the case, information about the role could be extracted from the asserted object(s) and verified (for example a name as a String).